# if any fields are empty the button should disable

Tags: vue.js

Here I am using vue.js code and made one form. Actually here I want to make a form button to disable until all the fields are filled completely if all the fields are filled then the form button should enable. Like if any fields are empty then the button should not clickable. if all the fields are filled then user can able to click the button.

```
  <div id="form">
    <input type="text" v-model='name'/>
    
    <input type="text" v-model='fname'/>
    
    <input type="text" v-model='phn'/>
    <button>Submit</button>
  </div>
```

```
new Vue({
  el: '#form',
  data: {
    name: '',
    fname: '',
    phn: ''

  },
  methods: {}
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what you need for this:
`:disabled` is a shorthand for `v-bind:disabled`.
And to check if a string is empty we need to take a property's length.
e.g.
`this.propertyname.length`.

I am using computed prop here, it allows us to check the true/false value on the fly (by changing any of the affected properties the computed property is updated), and that is why we are using `isBtnDisabled` as a property (w/o parentheses - that is why it is called computed properties), and not a method/function which must be called with a parentheses.

**EDITED:**

I have added a shorter version in code comments (more elegant way) to check the empty fields by [Boussadjra Brahim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8172857/boussadjra-brahim).

```js
    <template>
      <div id="form">
        <input type="text" v-model="name" />
    
        <input type="text" v-model="fname" />
    
        <input type="text" v-model="phn" />
        <button :disabled="isBtnDisabled">Submit</button>
      </div>
    </template>
    
    <script>
    export default {
      data: function () {
        return {
          name: "",
          fname: "",
          phn: "",
        };
      },
      computed: {
        isBtnDisabled() {
          // comment; the shorter version proposed by Boussadjra Brahim
          // return !(this.name && this.fname && this.phn)
          return (
            this.name.length === 0 ||
            this.fname.length === 0 ||
            this.phn.length === 0
          );
        },
      },
    };
    </script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Add a computed property that check if the all fields are set :

```
<button :disabled="isDisabled">Submit</button>
```

then

```
new Vue({
  el: '#form',
  data: {
    name: '',
    fname: '',
    phn: ''

  },
computed:{
  isDisabled(){
       return !(this.name && this.fname && this.phn)
 }
}
})
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#form',
  data: {
    name: '',
    fname: '',
    phn: ''

  },
  methods: {},
  computed: {
    disabled(){
      return !this.name || !this.fname || !this.phn;
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="form">
    <input type="text" v-model='name'/>
    
    <input type="text" v-model='fname'/>
    
    <input type="text" v-model='phn'/>
    <button :disabled="disabled">Submit</button>
  </div>
```

`computed` may work for this kind of purpose

Comment: Thanks for the solutions and it is working fine. but can we change the color like if the button is in disabled state then the button color should be lightgray and when button is in enable state then the button color should green

Comment: You might have a look at Vuetify and use `<v-btn color="success" :disabled=disabled>`. If you run into problems, please search existing SO questions.